# What is equivalent to hadoop-core-xxx.jar in hadoop 2.7.1

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, gps, giraph

I am working on Stanford's GPS (graph processing system) framework for distributed processing of graphs. The framework uses hadoop. As per GPS documentation, installing GPS requires copying hadoop-core-xxx.jar file to be copied in its libs directory. But, I found that hadoop-core-xxx.jar is not present in hadoop 2.7.1. What is equivalent to the hadoop core file in 2.7.1 version?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: check for hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-xxx.jar

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [hadoop-common](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common). Here's [hadoop-common-2.7.1](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.7.1/hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar).

Answer (score 0):

You can download the necessary hadoop-core jar file from [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/1.2.1/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar). I'm using it with hadoop 2.6, it must work with 2.7.1 as well.

Comment: I get an error with earlier versions: HDFS IO error
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4

Comment: I got the same error as Thiago. This is not a working solution.